# Last Remaining Blank in splicing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Problem**
I have been working on this code for a little while now and I'm not sure how to solve. I am taking in 3 values from inputs and trying to clean out all the blank spaces "" in the array however when I run the code it returns this:

```
["mm", "111", "100"]
["inches", "222", "95"]
["phi", "33", "55"]
[""]  // <---- **How to rid this**
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sub').click(function() {
    var my_arr = [];
    var split;
    $('td').each(function() {
      my_arr.push($(this).children().val());
      for (var e = my_arr.length - 1; e--;) {
        if (my_arr[e] === "") my_arr.splice(e, 1);


        var i, j, chunk = 3;
        for (i = 0, j = my_arr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
          split = my_arr.slice(i, i + chunk);
          console.log(split);
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-content">
        <div class="inner-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--    Header Text     -->
                    <div class="col-sm-10 text">
                        <h1><strong>SAGA</strong> Data Form</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-box">
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>Enter Data Below</h3>
                                <p>Please Enter Data to be converted</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            <form action="" class="login-form" method="post" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <form id="add_name" name="add_name">
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table align="center" class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
                                                <!--    Form Titles     -->
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Select</th>
                                                    <th>Text1</th>
                                                    <th>Text2</th>
                                                    <th></th><!--    Form Elements       -->
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><select class="unit selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" id="basic">
                                                        <option value="mm">
                                                            Millimeters
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option value="micron">
                                                            Micron
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option value="phi">
                                                            Phi
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option value="inches">
                                                            Inches
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option value="Mesh">
                                                            Mesh
                                                        </option>
                                                    </select></td>
                                                    <td><input class="form-control name_list" id="unitVal" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Unit Here" type="text" value="75000"></td>
                                                    <td><input class="form-control name_list" id="percent" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Percent Finer Here" type="text"></td>
                                                    <td><button class="btn btn-success" id="add" name="add" type="button">Add More</button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div><!-- Place BTN here to submitt form          -->
                                    </form>
                                </div><button class="btn" id="sub" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: add a check to see if the length equals 0

Comment: `split = my_arr.slice(i, i + chunk).filter(x=>x)`

Comment: @Malk Your script this returns []

Comment: What do you expect from this `$(this).children().val()` ? did you mean `.html()` or `.text()` ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH The question says he's getting the value of inputs. The HTML must be like `<td><input></td>`.

Comment: I expect the values of those inputs, why @IsmailRBOUH

Comment: You `td` has one element `input` ? or could you please add your HTML !

Comment: Instead of splicing array, you could check if value is `""` before pushing to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try excluding value from array

```
  var val = $(this).children().val();
  if (val !== "") {
    my_arr.push(val); 
  }
```